# Is there a way to make ng-multiselect-dropdown opens upwards?

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-multiselect-dropdown

Can i make ng-multiselect opens upwards?

[This is my sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qjkp2.png)

I want to make "SKU" and the other multiselect dropdowns open upwards to keep the content inside the div whenever user scrolls down the sidebar.

This is my dropdown:
[SKU multiselect when it is in open state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuKvL.png)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try getting the corresponding class name of that last dropdown(:last-child) and programmatically change its position values.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Would you mind making this a comment instead?